# Call web service from js file(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, web-services

i am creating a web app in MVC5 in which i need to call a web service from my javascript file,

in asp.net i used to call like

```
$http.get('/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid', {
        params: {
        }
    })
```

but in MVC5 it is showing me error

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/welcomegrid'
```

i tried this also

```
$http.get("http://localhost:50353/Models/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid", {
        params:
        {

        }
    })
```

but i am facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

you can use  below angularjs code,

```
$scope.getData = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
        .then(function(response){ 
            $scope.details = response.data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

for more help [Consuming Rest API Calls in AngularJS using $http Service](http://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/angularjs-tutorial/consuming-rest-api-calls-angularjs-using-http-service/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:-

```
$http.get("http://localhost:50353/Models/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid")
.then(function(response){
    //This function will be executed when the request was completed successfully
}, function(response){
    //This function will be executed when the request was not successful.
})
```

Here `response.data` will contain the data from the server .
This response object has various attributes ,You can check out more on this link :-
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to communicate with an old school web service I highly recommend wrapping it on the server side by adding it as a service reference. By doing so you will be able to expose it as a JSON service which most of the client side applications today including your AngularJS application would prefer to communicate with. For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx